# Magento Patch SUPEE-10570 update error

Tags: patches

I am trying to patch my site with SUPEE 10570 but I am having the error below

```
can't find file to patch at input line 1171
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
|index bbdc417..fa5167a 100644
|--- app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
|+++ app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
```

I checked my server an noticed that there is no file called "app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv" my previous developer delated

> app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv

for whatever reason I don't know. Would I be able to upload a new "app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv" file onto the server for the Patch then remove it after or I can just leave the "app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv" file after the patch with no issues. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download a new magento installation matching your current magento version and reupload this file to your server.
Since this is just a translation file you can safely keep the file after re-adding it.
Deleting it won't harm your site either.

You could also alter your patch file to skip this file. In that case you'll have to remove te following lines from your patch file and run your patch again

```
diff --git app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
index bbdc417..fa5167a 100644
--- app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
+++ app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv
@@ -713,6 +713,7 @@
 "The product has been deleted.","The product has been deleted."
 "The product has been duplicated.","The product has been duplicated."
 "The product has been saved.","The product has been saved."
+"HTML tags are not allowed in SKU attribute.","HTML tags are not allowed in SKU attribute."
 "The product has required options","The product has required options"
 "The review has been deleted","The review has been deleted"
 "The review has been saved.","The review has been saved."
```

Comment: That solve the issue when I delated the line for `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv` and it skipped  now I have sames one for `diff --git app/locale/en_US/Mage_ImportExport.csv app/locale/en_US/Mage_ImportExport.csv
|index fc3aa7f..cd8e9ec 100644
|--- app/locale/en_US/Mage_ImportExport.csv
|+++ app/locale/en_US/Mage_ImportExport.csv` should I go ahead and delete the line in the patch like before?

Comment: You're welcome! :)